# Incomprehensible in Javascript function

Tags: javascript

i have incomprehensible in Javascript, i have defined both of function but browser consol says that i have syntax error. What is wrong with tis and how can i fix it?

html and css code:

```
<style> 
div.container {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

div.box {
    width: 150px;
    border: 3px solid coral;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="box" id="box1">This is BOX1.</div>
<div class="box" id="box2">This is BOX2.</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

<p>Two 150 pixels boxes inside a 300 pixels container. It should fit nicely, but because of the borders and padding, the two boxes take up more space than 150 pixels each. This "problem" can be solved by setting the boxSizing property to "border-box".</p>




<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="removeHandler()"> Remove </button>
```

and Javascript code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {

    document.getElementById("box1").style.boxSizing = "border-box";
    document.getElementById("box2").style.boxSizing = "border-box";
}


function removeHandler() {
document.getElementById("box1").removeEventListener("style.boxSizing", removeHandler);
</script>
```

Comment: you missed the last '}'

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket `}` at the end.

Comment: Ah yea. but second function doesn't work still

Comment: I'd suggest, in future, referring to [JS Hint](http://jshint.com/), or [JS Lint](http://jslint.com/). Also, where did you define the `style.boxSizing` event, because that is not a native event.

Comment: I don't know. I just wanted to make second function, that would be able to remove first function. but is doesn't work

Comment: Maybe you should post the actual error message?

Comment: I have no message, first function works but second not.

Answer (score 1):

Change your last function to this:

```
function removeHandler() {
    document.getElementById("box1").removeEventListener("style.boxSizing", removeHandler);
}
```

You were missing the last bracket, causing your syntax error.